# How can i get date for factory reset when i did using ADB in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am looking to get the date for factory reset for attached android devices.
Actually i have to check it from my java code using ADB command.How can i get it if possible?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

This information is very vendor specific, and in general should NOT be available.

During factory reset (also known as master clear, master reset, hard reset) everything on device is reset to original factory state, such that nothing, not a single file or setting from previous device user remains.

This is designed such that you can sell your device after hard reset and not worry about any of your settings or pictures to be available to new owner. Or, you might want to return your device back to manufacturer, but be sure that none of your personal data is exposed.

Obviously, with this in mind, it should be clear that all device user partitions will be reformatted, often with secure erase option (it is typically available on eMMC devices).

The only hope to get time of last hard reset would be if vendor-implemented hard reset routine had stored this timestamp somewhere in the configuration partition(s) at the time of hard reset. But, I don't think that many vendors (if any) are actually bothering to do it.